# tornado logging formatter

Tags: python, logging, tornado

How can I override (or set formatter) default tornado's logging, I'd like to add remote_addr varriable to all logging messages. I try to set logging.Formatter("...") in application run section, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the source code http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/_modules/tornado/options.html#enable_pretty_logging, `tornado` does not allow generic formatting of log messages.

If you want your own format, you'll have to disable `tornado`'s logging and initialize your own logging handlers.

Comment: how would you do this?

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.removeHandler